# What is the inherent connection between 5 and being armed?

Tags: translation, shemot-exodus

Throughout Rav Hirsch's commentary on the Torah we find a deeper connection between related words. (i.e. Vayikra (5:15) "מַעַל is related to the me’il – robe of the Kohen gadol – as begged “garment” is related to bagad “faithless”.) Therefore, do Torah sources discuss an inherent connection between the number **five** in relation to being armed Shemos (13:18) seen below?

[Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0213.htm) translates (Shemos 13:18):

> וַיַּסֵּב אֱלֹהִים אֶת-הָעָם דֶּרֶךְ הַמִּדְבָּר, יַם-סוּף;
>   **וַחֲמֻשִׁים** עָלוּ בְנֵי-יִשְׂרָאֵל, מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרָיִם. "But God led the people about, by the way of the wilderness by the Red Sea; and the children of Israel went up **armed** out of the land of Egypt."

Note: I'm *not* looking for the Rashi quoted [here](http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/parsha/orchards/archives/001B%27shalach.htm) that "'chamushim' is from the root 'chamaish'- 5 showing only 1/ 5 of the Jews came out of Egypt. Or the Targum Yonasan ben Uziel who writes "*Chamushim* stems from the root 'chamaish'- that each family left Egypt with 5 kids!" What is the ***inherent*** connection between 5 and being armed?

Comment: I would think that Rav Hirsch, himself, would comment on this, no? My surmising - One needs his five fingers to use weapons? In a sense, English has a similar relationship. Why is using weapons calmed "arming"?

Comment: Note that many stridently argue against Rav Hirch's view, noting a dearth of evidence and indeed counter evidence on linguistic grounds (and his predecessors in the Torah commentary department). Accordingly, there is likely no connection whatsoever. However, with enough creativity you can connect any two random things.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by **inherent** connection. I would think that the reason for Rashi and the Targum is that it is not an *inherent* connection but a connection *al pi drash*

Comment: Might be something about making a fist.

Comment: IMO this is on-topic, as it asks about the connection between words _specifically according to the Torah-learning style of Rabbi Hirsch_, i.e. it's a Torah question. If I were to click reopen, this would reopen, as I'm a moderator; but consider this my unofficial nonbinding reopen vote.

Answer (score 7):

The Baal Haturim there connects the idea of being armed with the number five; corresponding to the five types of weapons mentioned in Yechezkel.

> וחמושים. מזויינים על שם חמשה מיני כלי זיין הנזכרים בפסוק מגן וצנה ורומח וחצים ומקל יד דכתיב (יחזקאל לט, ט) ויצאו יושבי ערי ישראל ובערו והשיקו בנשק ומגן וצנה בקשת ובחצים ובמקל יד וברומח.‏